# Select a column if condition is met

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a view in MySQL from a couple tables (in WordPress/WooCommerce), the final result should look like this:

```
id    name    price   sku 
1     test    9.99    ABC
```

The tables to source the data are set up like this:

**PRODUCTS TABLE**

```
id    name
1     test
```

**METADATA TABLE**

```
product_id   meta_key   value
1            price      9.99
1            sku        ABC
```

The part I am having trouble with is how to get the meta_key to show up as a column in the final view table.

This is what I have so far (it doesn't work, but maybe it helps to show the logic I want to use, see lines 3-4 below):

```
SELECT 
  products.id,
  products.name,
  metadata.value AS price IF meta_key = price
  metadata.value AS sku IF meta_key = sku
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `metadata`
ON products.id = metadata.product_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add additional conditions to your join to filter the meta_key, and do a join for each type of key you want to make a column:

```
SELECT 
  products.id,
  products.name,
  price.value AS price
  sku.value AS sku
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `metadata` AS price ON products.id = price.product_id AND price.meta_key = 'price'
INNER JOIN `metadata` AS sku ON products.id = sku.product_id AND sku.meta_key = 'sku'
```

Mind you, this will only show product that have both a price and sku in the metadata table.
If you want to show products that have either/or, change the `INNER JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s

Comment: hum.. are price and sku really tables? I did not know we could refer to the value of a field that way

Comment: no, in this case they are aliases of the metadata table, which were specified on the join

Comment: this is great. new realms of sql glory opens in my mind.